# serializing relationships ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

Okay so this is my json response:

item:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "rodzzlessa",
        "slug": "rodzzlessa"
     }
}
```

collection:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 34,
        "name": "HDG common nails 50lbs",
        "slug": "hdg-common-nails-50lbs4569",
        "description": "Accusantium ipsam impedit omnis sint dolorum.",
        "image_src": "nail-box-angle.png",
        "categories": {
            "data": [
                {
                     "id": 2,
                     "name": "nails",
                    "image_src": "nails-icon.png"
                }
             ]
         }
     }
  ]
}
```

I was able to make a serialzier for the main response:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    extractArray: function(store, typeClass, payload) {
        payload.products = payload.data;
        delete payload.data;

        return this._super(store, typeClass, payload);
    }
});
```

Everything works great what I'm having an issue with is the relationships in this case a `categories: DS.hasMany('category')`. The error I get is:

```
A (subclass of DS.Model) record was pushed into the store with the value of categories being '{data: [object Object]}', but categories is a hasMany relationship so the value must be an array.
```

So my questions is which method should I edit to be able to serialize the relationship same way I did to its parent? I've added the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` to make my life a lot easier with relationships.

Comment: Can't you handle this in the same method: extractArray? It's not ideal but you have access to the payload. I'd create a function like `normalizeRelatedArrays` and iterate over the payload keys and look for childrens containing the `data` key as value and remove it. In the end, Ember expects to have "categories": [ { ... item 1}, { ... item 2}]

Comment: @enspandi could you please expand more? If you wouldn't mind maybe an example?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, the error results from having and object inside of the `categories` key:

```
A (subclass of DS.Model) record was pushed into the store with the value of categories being '{data: [object Object]}', but categories is a hasMany relationship so the value must be an array.
```

Therefore you have to extract the array from this block `categories: { "data": [...] }` to `categories: [...]`.

You could simply iterate over the payload like this:

```
var idx, key, item;
var len = payload.data.length;
for (idx=0; idx<len; idx++) {
  item = payload.data[idx];
  for (key in item) {
    if (item[key].hasOwnProperty('data')) {
      item[key] = item.data;
    }
  }
}
```